# Pass parameters between drawer stacks react-navigation

Tags: react-native, parameter-passing, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

My router setup is as below

```
import { createAppContainer, createDrawerNavigator, createStackNavigator, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";

import Home from "./components/Home";
import Search from "./components/Search";
import Map from "./components/Map";

import Login from "./components/Login";
import ForgotPassword from "./components/ForgotPassword";

import SideMenu from "./SideMenu";

const DashboardStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Home },
    Search : {screen : Search}
  }
);

const MapStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Map: { screen: Map },
  }
);

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: { screen: Login },
    ForgotPassword: { screen: ForgotPassword },
  }
);

export const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Dashboard: { screen: DashboardStack },
    Map: { screen: MapStack },
  },
  {
    contentComponent: SideMenu,
    drawerWidth: 250
  }
);

export const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Drawer: { screen: DrawerStack },
    Auth: { screen: AuthStack },
  },
  {
    // initialRouteName: "Drawer",
    headerMode: 'none',
    mode: 'modal',
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(DrawerStack);
```

Everything working fine, just a small issue. When I navigate to search screen from home and then switch to the Map screen with parameters, those parameters are not reaching to the Map screen.

My current setup is at [codepan](https://snack.expo.io/ByIh8kNrr)

Comment: Looking at the code you are passing "name: 'Janak'" to Map, is that the value you are not finding? or are you able to pass it?

Comment: Yes that value I am not able to get in that Map, its some silly mistake I can't find, generally we are able to get that if they are in same stack but here we have different stack so not sure.

Comment: Could it simply be that you have to put "" around name? like     `this.props.navigation.navigate('Map', { "name": 'Janak' });`

Comment: I changed it as per your suggestion and removed "" but not working

Comment: I said to add them, not to remove them, at least looking at codepen

Comment: Sorry made a blunder so confused, checked adding also, but not working

Comment: Could you please update your code to show, how you are accessing that param?

Comment: your response would help me to help you :)

Comment: I have setup the code pan at https://snack.expo.io/ByIh8kNrr, please have a look

Comment: In your snack code in Map component I cannot see the code where you are accessing the params..

Comment: Please confirm if you are accessing the values this way in Map component `const name = this.props.navigation.getParam('name', 'Janak');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your MapStack and your Map screen both have the same name, 'Map'.

Just replace the MapStack route to something else like 'MapStack' and you'll get the params.

See here: https://snack.expo.io/SyTFUPZUB

```
export const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Dashboard: { screen: DashboardStack },
    MapStack: { screen: MapStack },
  },
  {
    contentComponent: SideMenu,
    drawerWidth: 250
  }
);
```

Comment: That must not be of any problem, as react-navigation only identifies component by screen name not directly.

Comment: @GokulKulkarni I am pretty sure what is happening is that RN send the request to the stack instead of the screen and then the stack does not forward the parameter to the screen. If you try the snack you'll see it works.

Comment: the flow goes like this, the request is of course sent to stack first along with params and then to the screen, if there r multiple screen it'll send to the first one specified or if initialRoute is specified then to that component along with the params. If whatever you're using works then it's a bug in react-navigation

Comment: @GokulKulkarni Fair enough, but it works. What I am saying is that the ID was the same for the stack and the screen within the stack. It could be that the stack is just loading the first screen instead of passing the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

@sfratini is right

The issue is indeed "Map" key being present in two places.

So navigation.navigate("Map") will navigate to MapStack.
Navigating to stack means going to current screen of that stack which defaults to initialRouteName or first screen in the stack.

To verify this, add another screen as first screen in MapStack and check the behaviour.

So, solution to your issue is to rename "Map" key to something else, as suggested by @sfratini.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine by just adding map screen to dashboard stack

```
const DashboardStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Home },
    Search : {screen : Search},
     Map: { screen: Map }
  }
);
```

then use

```
this.props.navigation.getParam('name', 'name is coming')
```

to get the name params value

here is the code 
https://snack.expo.io/HyEFZeyLB

Answer (score 0):

you can reach the parameters in your Map screen like following:

update this :

```
render() {
return (
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <Text>Map</Text>
  </SafeAreaView>
)
}
```

to this :

```
render() {
return (
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <Text>{this.props.navigation.state.params.name}</Text>
  </SafeAreaView>
)
}
```

and you have to put your Map screen in with home and search Stack like following:

```
import { createAppContainer, createDrawerNavigator, createStackNavigator, 
createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";

import Home from "./components/Home";
import Search from "./components/Search";
import Map from "./components/Map";

import Login from "./components/Login";
import ForgotPassword from "./components/ForgotPassword";

import SideMenu from "./SideMenu";

const DashboardStack = createStackNavigator(
{
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Search : {screen : Search},
  Map: { screen: Map },
}
);


const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
{
  Login: { screen: Login },
  ForgotPassword: { screen: ForgotPassword },
}
);

export const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator(
{
  Dashboard: { screen: DashboardStack },
},
{
  contentComponent: SideMenu,
  drawerWidth: 250
}
);

export const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
  Drawer: { screen: DrawerStack },
  Auth: { screen: AuthStack },
} ,
{
  // initialRouteName: "Drawer",
  headerMode: 'none',
  //mode: 'modal',
}
);

export default createAppContainer(DrawerStack);
```

the result from your snak :

[image]

hope this will help.